# Designing more complex database for ASP.NET MVC 5 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, database-design

I wanna create a database diagram for ASP.NET MVC 5 code first project. In this project first of all, I am gonna create a fabric. Fabric table has many-to-many relationship with Yarn table and a fabric can contain one or more yarn. Similarly Fabric and Order tables have many-to-many relationship and I want to calculate total price and store it in FabricOrder table taking "UnitPriceOfFabric" from "FabricYarn" table. In this situation I want to ask how can I make a relation between "FabricOrder" and "FabricYarn". And this design in picture is correct or not. İf it is wrong how can I improve it.

Thanks..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't look like the best design to cater this requirement. I have think there is no need of FabricOrder table as Order just needs to know which Fabric has been ordered for which Fabric Id should be sufficient. Also Unit Price of fabric should be stored in Fabric table as this is an attribute of Fabric and not going to change with combination of Yarn.

I would have gone for something like this -

[Improved ER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2pTg.jpg)

I have kept the unit price in order table as well because it could change in future so this will retain the history.

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Firstly Thank you so much for your answer. Actually I created one to many relationship between yarn and fabric tables. But then I decide to change it. First of all I will create some kind of yarn with unit price then go to the fabric page I add there master details, I mean, in this page user enter the name of fabric and adding one or more yarn with percentageOfUsing I use drop down list for yarns and yarn's unit price take automatically then I calculate them and find fabricUnitPrice. I am new on mvc 5 code first. Will your ER diagram work in this situation?

Comment: First of all I will create some kind of yarn with unit price - Insert rows in Yarn Table,   in this page user enter the name of fabric and adding one or more yarn with percentageOfUsing  - at this time in the same transaction, create an entry in fabric table with some unique id and add rows in FabricYarn corresponding to the combination you selected on the screen and calculate the price of yarn in this fabric unit based on percentage and calculate the total and update in fabric table.

Comment: Thanks again for your comment, I am want to ask something about calculation. Where should I do the calculation of fabric unit price. In client side or server side. Which will be sense?